# C++, клиент-серверное приложение на windows

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер, криптография, winsock

пишу клиент-серверное приложение, захотел добавить функционал.
1.Клиент отправляет шифрованные данные на сервер.
2.Сервер принимает данные и отправляет их обратно клиенту.
3.Если данные совпали, то клиент отправляет оригинальные данные на сервер.

Но что-то не работает, данные приходят на сервер, а дальше он либо их не отправляет клиенту, либо клиент не может их грамотно считать.

Server.cpp

````
#define _WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // требование Microsoft


#include <iostream>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

#include "decrypt.h"
#include "Servert.h"



#define SERVER_PORT "666"
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1024

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4005)
#pragma warning(disable:4101)

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

std::atomic<int> counter(0);
std::mutex mtx;


int check(SOCKET s)
{
    if (s == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Socket Error" << endl;
        closesocket(s);
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int ClientID()
{
    mtx.lock();
    ++counter;
    mtx.unlock();
    return counter;
}


//обработка клиента
DWORD WINAPI HandleClient(LPVOID lpParam)
{
    std::pair<SOCKET, int>* params = reinterpret_cast<std::pair<SOCKET, int>*>(lpParam);
    SOCKET ClientSocket = params->first;
    int ClientID = params->second;
    char recvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    int result;
    int count_messange = 1;

    do
    {
        ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
        result = recv(ClientSocket, recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer), 0); // получаем информацию от клиентского сокета (шифрованные данные)

        if (result > 0)
        {
            cout << "(" << count_messange << ") Client [" << ClientID << "]: SHA256 = " << recvBuffer << endl;
            result = send(ClientSocket, recvBuffer, result, 0); // отправляем клиенту сообщение из Буффера
            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Failed to send data back" << endl;
                check(ClientSocket);
                return 1;
            }

        }
        else if (result == 0)
        {
            cout << "Connection closing..." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Recv failed with error" << endl;
            check(ClientSocket);
            return 1;
        }
        ++count_messange;

        // получаем оригинальные данные от клиентского сокета 
        ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
        result = recv(ClientSocket, recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer), 0);
        if (result > 0)
        {
            cout << "(" << count_messange << ") Client [" << ClientID << "]: original data = " << recvBuffer << endl;
            // result = send(ClientSocket, recvBuffer, result, 0); // отправляем клиенту сообщение из Буффера
            if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                cout << "Failed to send data back" << endl;
                check(ClientSocket);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        else if (result == 0)
        {
            cout << "Connection closing..." << endl;
        }

        else
        {
            cout << "Recv failed with error" << endl;
            check(ClientSocket);
            return 1;
        }

    } while (result > 0);

    result = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "shutdown client socket failed" << endl;
        check(ClientSocket);
        return 1;
    }

    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData; // Версия текущей библиотеки Winsock 2.2
    ADDRINFO hints; // продсказки для клиента о сервере
    ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL; // куда получим данные о сервере
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET; // Клиентский сокет
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET; // Слушающий сокет


    const char* sendBuffer = "Your enter messange to server!"; // для сервера
    char recvBuffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

    int result; // код значения

    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed, resilt " << result << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "----Server Activated----" << endl;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints)); // зануляем все поля hints (все параметры hints равны 0)
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // ethernet
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // протокол TCP/IP
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // информация для пассивной стороны (т.к сервер пассивная сторона, а клиент активная)

    result = getaddrinfo(NULL, SERVER_PORT, &hints, &addrResult);  // информация и сервере
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "getaddrinfo failed with error: " << result << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    ListenSocket = socket(addrResult->ai_family, addrResult->ai_socktype, addrResult->ai_protocol);
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket creation failed" << endl;
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult); // освобождаем addrResult
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    result = bind(ListenSocket, addrResult->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(addrResult->ai_addrlen));

    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Binding socket failed" << endl;
        check(ListenSocket);
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
        return 1;
    }

    result = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN); // второй параметр - сколько клиентов может слушать сервер


    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "Listen socket failed" << endl;
        check(ListenSocket);
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "Server listing on port: " << SERVER_PORT << endl;


    while (true)
    {
        ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
        if (check(ClientSocket))
        {
            cout << "Accepting socket failed" << endl;
            check(ListenSocket);
            freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            std::pair<SOCKET, int> parametrs = std::make_pair(ClientSocket, ClientID());
            cout << "Client connected!" << endl;
            HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, HandleClient, &parametrs, 0, NULL);
        }

    }

    check(ClientSocket);
    freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    return 0;

}



----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Client.cpp

#define _WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN // требование MS


#include <iostream>
#include <Winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <windows.h>

#include "Clientt.h"
#include "encrypt.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma warning(disable:4005)

using namespace std;

void check(SOCKET& socket, ADDRINFO* addrResult)
{
    closesocket(socket); // Закрываем соккет
    socket = INVALID_SOCKET; // обнуляем
    freeaddrinfo(addrResult);
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    ADDRINFO hints; // продсказки для клиента о сервере
    ADDRINFO* addrResult = NULL; // куда получим данные о сервере
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET; // пока не создали соккет

    int result = 0; // код значения

    result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "WSAStartup failed, resilt " << result << endl;
        return 1;
    }


    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints)); // зануляем все поля hints (все параметры hints равны 0)
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET; // ethernet
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP; // протокол TCP/IP

    result = getaddrinfo("localhost", "666", &hints, &addrResult);  // информация и сервере
    if (result != 0)
    {
        cout << "getaddrinfo failed with error: " << result << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    ConnectSocket = socket(addrResult->ai_family, addrResult->ai_socktype, addrResult->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "Socket creation failed" << endl;
        freeaddrinfo(addrResult); // освобождаем addrResult
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    result = connect(ConnectSocket, addrResult->ai_addr, static_cast<int>(addrResult->ai_addrlen));

    if (result == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "Enable connect to server" << endl;
        check(ConnectSocket, addrResult);
        return 1;
    }

    char sendBuffer[512];
    char recvBuffer[512];
    int recvbuflen = sizeof(recvBuffer);

    while (true) {
        cout << "Enter message: ";
        cin.getline(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer));
        char* EncryptMessange= encrypt(sendBuffer);
        cout << "Sending encrypted data..." << endl;

        result = send(ConnectSocket, EncryptMessange, static_cast<int>(strlen(EncryptMessange)), 0); // отправляем серверу шифрованные данные
        if (result == SOCKET_ERROR) 
        {
            cout << "Send failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            check(ConnectSocket, addrResult);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }
        ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
        result = recv(ConnectSocket, recvBuffer, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (result > 0) 
        {

            cout << "Received: " << recvBuffer << endl;
            ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
            
        }
        else if (result == 0) 
        {
            cout << "Connection closed by server." << endl;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Receive failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
            break;
        }

        if (result > 0)
        {
            if (equals(sendBuffer, recvBuffer))
            {
                cout << "Original data has been delivered: " << sendBuffer << endl;
                ZeroMemory(recvBuffer, sizeof(recvBuffer));
                ZeroMemory(sendBuffer, sizeof(sendBuffer));
                continue;                 
            }
            else if (result == 0)
            {
                cout << "Connection closed by server." << endl;
                break;             
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "Recieve failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
                break;
            }
        }      
    }

    check(ConnectSocket, addrResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}```
````